# Linux Invoke custom script during OS shutdown

Tags: linux, rhel

I wrote a simple JAVA application which runs as a service. When my application is up and running, I maintain the PID in a file which will be used while stopping the application.

**Issue:**

When I restart the OS the stop script is not called (not sure how to make this happen) and the old PID is left as it is in the PID file. Now, after reboot (which start my app) when I stop the app using stop script now my stop script will try to clean up all the PID listed in the file. Most of the time, I will get "No such process". But there are chance the same PID might have been used for some other process

**Question:**

How I can make sure my stop script will be invoked when I shutdown ore reboot the OS? I am looking a solution for RHEL environment.

Comment: Hint: Check out info on "runlevels". Particularly runlevels 0 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are looking for a init script. (startup/shutdown services at different run levels)

This is a good reference 
http://blog.rimuhosting.com/2009/09/30/one-java-init-script/

this has a good refernce to Linux init.d scripts

http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-custom-initd-script-on-fedora/

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for scripts that run after reboot, I guess you can write the script in `/etc/rc.local` and then you can start your service.

This script will run after all your init scripts have run while your machine starts. Using this you can delete the old PID file.